# How do I change just the starting point of an existing UIBezierPath?

Tags: uibezierpath

**How do I change just the starting point of an existing UIBezierPath? .. and leave all other points the same?**

I have definitely seen many posts on how to do this .. honestly, I just do not understand many of them

My existing path has **one** `.move(to:)` and **many** `.addLine(to:)`

My goal is:

(1) replace the `.move(to:)` with `.addLine(to:)` **and then**
(2) change one of the `.addLine(to:)` with `.move(to:)`

All other `CGPoints` stay the same.

In order to get the **new** starting point, I set:

```
savedPathPoint = myPath.currentPoint
```

**when** I stop the following motion.

At some point, I want to resume this following motion with the new starting point = `savedPathPoint` via

```
    myPath.move(to: savedPathPoint)

    let myAction = SKAction.follow(
                               myPath.cgPath,
                               asOffset: false,
                               orientToPath: true,
                               duration: 0.1)
    mySprite.run(myAction)
```

When I look at the above problem description, it really appears simple.

Nevertheless, its implementation alludes me.

Thanks bunches in advance for any hints whatsoever.

Comment: FYI, they state to accomplish changing the starting point to one in the middle of an existing **cgPath** requires a total rebuild of the whole path which would consume much time. They recommended investigating **CAAffirm** methodology

Comment: As far as I am concerned, those that staff the Apple Developers Forum are 100% indispensable.

Comment: *"My existing path has **one** `.move(to:)` and **many** `.addLine(to:)`"* ... How complex is your path? That is, how many is "many"?

Comment: Eight **.addLine(to**:)

Answer (score 0):

One `.move(to:)` and **8** `.addLine(to:)` means **9** points total. It will take almost no time to "re-build" the path.

Assuming you have:

```
var pts: [CGPoint]   // an array of 9 points
var startIDX: Int    // the index in the array where you want to "start"
```

you can use a func like this:

```
private func generatePath(from ptsArray:[CGPoint], startingAt: Int) -> CGPath {

    var idx = startingAt
    
    if idx > pts.count {
        idx = 0
    }
    
    var ptsCopy = Array(ptsArray[idx...])
    ptsCopy.append(contentsOf: ptsArray[0..<idx])
    
    let pth = CGMutablePath()
    pth.move(to: ptsCopy.removeFirst())
    while !ptsCopy.isEmpty {
        pth.addLine(to: ptsCopy.removeFirst())
    }
    
    // pth is now the same path, but
    //  starting at pts[idx] and
    //  ending at pts[idx-1]

    return pth
    
}
```

and call it with:

```
let newPath: CGPath = generatePath(from: pts, startingAt: startIDX)
```

Comment: I am definitely not ignoring you. I have learned a lot from you. Currently, I am trying to make the correct changes so your startingAt is a CGPoint not an Int. I believe you could do this change in a short time. But I don’t want you to give the answer because I won’t learn much by copying you. I need to do it myself. After all, my objective is to learn and to optimize its retention